# Two functions uses same code, only one results in"no database selected" error

Tags: php, mysqli

I am pretty much a beginner in php and mysql. Can someone explain why this error is coming up and how to fix it? I have put my database connection code into its own function and was planning on using it in my other functions. However, when I do, one of my other functions return a "UNCAUGHT MYSQLI_SQL_EXCEPTION: NO DATABASE SELECTED" error. I'm not sure what's going wrong.

My code:

db_connect.php

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT); 
$host = 'localhost'; 
$user = 'user'; 
$password = 'password';
$forumDb = 'forumDb';
```

functions:

```
function connectForum() {
    require_once '../php/db_connect.php';
    static $forum;
    $connectForum = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $forumDb);

    //check connection to database and set $forum to $connectForum if dB connection successful
    if (!$connectForum) {
        die('Connect Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $forum = $connectForum;
    return $forum;
}

//display main categories from database; this works fine
function dispMain() {
    //connect to forumDb and select everything from mainCateg table
    $forum = connectForum();
    $query = "SELECT * ";
    $query .= "FROM mainCateg";

    //form query and test if successful; die if not
    $result = mysqli_query($forum, $query) or die(mysqli_error($forum));

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<section class='section-group'>";
        echo "<h1>{$row['mainTitle']}</h1><p>{$row['mainDesc']}";
        dispSub($row['mainId']);
        echo "</section>";
    }
}

//this function throws an error
function dispSub($mid) {
    $forum = connectForum();
    $query = "SELECT mainId, mainTitle, subId, subTitle, subDesc ";
    $query .= "FROM mainCateg, subCateg ";
    $query .= "WHERE ($mid = ?) AND ($mid = ?)";

    //prepare statment and bind parmeters
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($forum, $query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ii', $main_mid, $sub_mid);

    //set variable values
    $main_mid = "mainCateg.mainId";
    $sub_mid = "subCateg.subMainId";

    //execute prepared statement, bind result, and echo info using fetch
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $mainId, $mainTitle, $subId, $subTitle, $subDesc);

    while ($row = mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
        echo "<p>Test echo</p>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show db_connect.php?

Comment: @Dmitry yeah, I just added it

Comment: Could you show us the full error message. Which line is it coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Your dispSub function is running in a loop, then the connectForum() function is being called again and again which is not good. I have tried to optimize your code a little bit by using global.

> Some predefined variables in PHP are "superglobals", which means that
>   they are always accessible, regardless of scope - and you can access
>   them from any function, class or file without having to do anything
>   special.

```
<?php

    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT); 


    $host = '127.0.0.1'; 
    $user = 'root'; 
    $password = '';
    $forumDb = 'aaaa';
    $connectForum = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $forumDb); 
    //check connection to database and set $forum to $connectForum if dB connection successful 
    if (!$connectForum)
    {
        die('Connect Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error()); 
    }

    //display main categories from database; this works fine
    function dispMain() 
    {
        global $connectForum;

        //connect to forumDb and select everything from mainCateg table
        $forum = connectForum(); 
        $query = "SELECT * "; 
        $query .= "FROM mainCateg"; 

        //form query and test if successful; die if not  
        $result = mysqli_query($forum, $query) or die(mysqli_error($forum)); 

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            echo "<section class='section-group'>"; 
                echo "<h1>{$row['mainTitle']}</h1><p>{$row['mainDesc']}"; 
                dispSub($row['mainId']);
            echo "</section>";  
        }
    }

    //this function throws an error 
    function dispSub($mid)
    {
        global $connectForum;

        $query = "SELECT mainId, mainTitle, subId, subTitle, subDesc "; 
        $query .= "FROM mainCateg, subCateg "; 
        $query .= "WHERE ($mid = ?) AND ($mid = ?)"; 

        //prepare statment and bind parmeters 
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($forum, $query); 
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ii', $main_mid, $sub_mid); 

        //set variable values 
        $main_mid = "mainCateg.mainId"; 
        $sub_mid = "subCateg.subMainId"; 

        //execute prepared statement, bind result, and echo info using fetch 
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); 
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $mainId, $mainTitle, $subId, $subTitle, $subDesc);

        while ($row = mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
        {
            echo "<p>Test echo</p>"; 
        }
    }

    ?>
```